# If $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are subgroups of (G,$\bullet$), then $H_{1}\triangle H_{2}$ is a subgroup of (G,$\bullet$) ? Prove or give a counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let (G,$\bullet$) be a group. If $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are subgroups
of (G,$\bullet$), then $H_{1}\triangle H_{2}$ is a subgroup of (G,$\bullet$)
where $\triangle$is the symmetric difference.

I think that is false.

My argument: Because (G,$\bullet$) is a group, then exist $e\in$
G where $e$ is the identity element. Now, because $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$
are subgroups of (G,$\bullet$) then $e$ $\in$ $H_{1}$ and $e$
$\in$ $H_{2}$. Then, for definition of intersection betwen sets,
we have that $e$ $\in$ $H_{1}\cap H_{2}$. Now by definition of
symmetric difference we have that $H_{1}\triangle H_{2}$ = ($H_{1}\cup H_{2})-(H_{1}\cap H_{2})$
. Then we have that $e$$\notin$ $H_{1}\triangle H_{2}$ and then,
because $H_{1}\triangle H_{2}$ don't have the identity element, we
have that $H_{1}\triangle H_{2}$ is not a group. It is my argument correct? What counterexample can I use to disprove it?

Comment: Your argument is correct, and thus *any* two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ will form a counterexample!

Comment: Incidentally, you can get a somewhat less trivial question by asking whether $(H_1\bigtriangleup H_2)\cup\{e\}$ is or can be a subgroup of $G$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct. For a counterexample, simply let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be the trivial subgroup. As commented by Greg Martin, according to your argument any two subgroups will form a counterexample. It's especially obvious when the subgroups are equal because then the symmetric difference is empty!

Comment: Just to be clear. The empty set it's not a group? And if the answer is no: Why? It just that I read in the book ''proofs and fundamentals'' and it says that the empty set is a group.

Comment: @ManuelVargas There is no such thing as an empty group. A group must have an identity element, so every group has at least one element.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @ManuelVargas No problem.